# AngularJS Custom Directive templateURL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filepath

Working on creating my first custom directive in AngularJS, but am having some problems when using the `templateURL` parameter; it doesn't actually request the page that I am attempting to call.

When I use the plain `template`parameter, it works as expected though.
I think that maybe my path being used in the `templateURL` may be incorrect??

**This is my HTML in my main page:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="formFields">
    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
    <div ng-sparkline person="person"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is my custom directive:**

```
myApp.directive('ngSparkline', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        person: '='
    },
    //template: '<p class="lead">Hi, {{person.name}}!</p>'
      templateURL: '/js/directives/formFields.html'
  }
});
```

**Here is my formFields.html  file:**

```
<p class="lead">Hey, {{person.name}}</p>
```

**This is how my app directory is laid out:**
My `directives.js` file is located in the `js` directory, while the `formFields.html` file is located in `/js/directives/...`
[image: directory layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a spelling(case) mistake. `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`

Comment: I edited my answer. You've just mis-spelled templateUrl

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that! Rookie move :)

Answer (score 2):

For one, you have miscased `templateUrl` as `templateURL`.
If this does not fix your problem, it might be because of the absolute URL.

Are you serving the file via a server or did you open it in a browser via the disk?

If your link is `file://C://www/html/js/directives`, the absolute path `/js/directives` targets `file://C:/js/directives`, where no template code lies, obviously. In that case you need to use relative paths.

Comment: This application is hosted on a server, so I know that my filepath is correct, based on other similar constructions of relative paths in the application.

Comment: The problem was the spelling mistake! Feeling dumb